# Let $f : [0, 1] → R$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) ≥ x^{3}$ for all $x ∈ [0, 1] $ with $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$ = 1/4 . Then $f(x)=x^{3}$

Tags: calculus

Let $f : [0, 1] → R$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) ≥ x^{3}$ for all $x ∈ [0, 1] $ with $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx = 1/4 . $Then $f(x) = x^{3}$ for all $x ∈ R.$

True/false$?$

If i have to consider only polynomials then the statement is true. What about other continuous functions $?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $h(x) = f(x) - x^3$, and the following result (prove it if you have to, it's not very difficult):

> If $h:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ is a continuous, non-negative function, and $\int_0^1 h(x) dx = 0$, then $h(x) = 0$.